# Multiple input field value into one array using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have some input fields like this

```
<input id="serial" type="text" name="serialname" class="serialclass"/>
<input id="serial" type="text" name="serialname" class="serialclass"/>
<input id="serial" type="text" name="serialname" class="serialclass"/>
<input id="serial" type="text" name="serialname" class="serialclass"/>
<input id="serial" type="text" name="serialname" class="serialclass"/>
<input id="serial" type="text" name="serialname" class="serialclass"/>
<input id="serial" type="text" name="serialname" class="serialclass"/>
```

I want to get values from all the input fields using jQuery and store it into a array.

Comment: An object id should be always unique!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Id's should be unique across DOM. So change your id's and use class to get all input values and push it to array.Try this:

```
var arr = [];
$("input.serialclass").each(function(){
    arr.push($(this).val());
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kunknown/96xDD/)**

Answer (score 2):

First ids have to be unique.

### Answer:

```
var arr = $('.serialclass').map(function(){
  return this.value;
}).get();
```